# Multiple Columns for First Level Dependent Dropdown List

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns that i am concerned with:

1. Group (Ferrous/Non-ferrous/etc.)
2. RI No. (Unique identifier)
3. Item Description (Name of the chosen RI No. item)
4. Supplier (Sellers of chosen RI No.)

The flow of data happens like this:
I select Group (say, Ferrous) --> In RI No. column, an automatic dropdown is created, showing RI Nos. of all items under Ferrous category show up --> I select a particular RI No. from this drop-down --> Item Description appears through VLOOKUP --> A drop-down of all sellers selling that item show up in in Supplier column.

Now, I wrote a code which does this work perfectly, but i was wondering if there was a way to make it so that:
I select Group (say, Ferrous) --> **In RI No. column AND in Item Description column**, an automatic dropdown is created, showing RI Nos. of all items under Ferrous category show up --> **If I select RI No., item description gets populated/If I select Item Description, RI No. gets populated** --> corresponding suppliers list show up as they do now.

Sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16qv-OgCIezEuaOm8fQdq91FiQbBny4MzGRIho9ZCY-E/edit#gid=1605627126

The code:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var wsopt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sorted items");
var opts = wsopt.getRange(2,1,wsopt.getLastRow()-1,13).getValues(); 
var firstlevelcolumn = 2;
var secondlevelcolumn = 5;
var thirdlevelcolumn= 6;
var wsopt2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("supplier details");
var opts2 = wsopt2.getRange(3,1,wsopt2.getLastRow()-1,12).getValues(); 


function onEdit(e) 
{ var activecell= e.range;
 var val = activecell.getValue();
 var r= activecell.getRow();
 var c= activecell.getColumn();
 var wsName= activecell.getSheet().getName();
 if (wsName == "JPS")
 { 
   if (wsName == "JPS" && c == firstlevelcolumn && r > 2)
   { applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);}
   if (wsName == "JPS" && c == secondlevelcolumn && r > 2) 
   { applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);} 
 }//JPS
 else if (wsName == "DDNI")
 {
   if (wsName == "DDNI" && c == firstlevelcolumn && r > 2)
   {applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);}
   if (wsName == "DDNI" && c == secondlevelcolumn && r > 2) 
   { applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);} 
 }//DDNI
}//close onEdiT

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r)
{
 if(val=== "") 
   {
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
   } else 
   {
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearContent(); 
     ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent(); 
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
     var filteredopts = opts.filter(function(o){return o[0]===val});
     var listToApply = filteredopts.map(function(o){return o[1]});
     var cell=ws.getRange(r,secondlevelcolumn);
     applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
   }//close else
}//close applyFirstLevelValidation

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r)
{
 if(val=== "") 
   {
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
   } else 
   {
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearContent(); 
     ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn).clearDataValidations();
     var firstlevelcolvalue = ws.getRange(r,firstlevelcolumn).getValue();
     var filteredopts2 = opts2.filter(function(o){return o[6]===firstlevelcolvalue && o[4]===val});
     var listToApply2 = filteredopts2.map(function(o){return o[0]});
     var cell2=ws.getRange(r,thirdlevelcolumn);
     applyValidationToCell(listToApply2,cell2);
   }//close else
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell) 
{ 
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Are Description and RI NO. display only? One idea would be to concatenate both fields when populating the drop-down. 
Since unfortunately Sheets Data Validation Drop-down doesn’t have a display+value behavior as in HTML for example, you’ll need to treat the current value (removing a separator and everything after/before) in case those fields are edited and need to be used as key value to search/populate the other field.

Comment: I don't really care about your work flow.  Please ask the question in terms of scripting.  Were here to help you with the scripting and we cannot possibly know everything about every ones work flow.